# Passing a Non-Contiguous Range from a Union into Outlook

Tags: excel, vba

A group of teachers (I am one) is using a spreadsheet to track missing assignments of students. The students' names are in column A, and missing assignments expand in columns to the right.

When an assignment is missing, the teacher puts their initial in the cell and right-clicks to add a comment about the assignment.
When the student submits the assignment, the teacher changes the cell's fill from nothing (xlNone) to yellow or grey.

We'd like Excel to send us a daily email that lists only the students with missing assignments in cells filled with xlNone along with the initial of the teacher or teachers.

This code does not error. The email object is constructed, but there is no data in the body of the email.

```vb
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()
'Thanks to code by Tim Williams and Ron de Bruin

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim ci As Long
    Set rng = Nothing
    
    For Each cell In Sheet1.Range("C4:Z100").Cells
        ci = cell.Interior.ColorIndex
        If (ci = -4142 Or ci = 2 Or ci = 15 Or ci = 16) And Not IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = cell
            Else
                Set rng = Application.Union(rng, cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.Select
        
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "teacher1@school.org, teacher2@school.org"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the list of students with missing work"
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Send
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Thanks to Ron de Bruin's page
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to paste the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

I commented `On Error Resume Next` out as suggested and get an error

> 'Type Mismatch'

Looking at the sheet, the various cells are highlighted.

Comment: Please remove _On Error Resume Next_ to get possible error message

Comment: Thanks Shrotter. I commented them out as you suggested and get a 'Type Mismatch' error. Looking at the sheet, the various cells are highlighted though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello middleschoolteacher,

**UPDATED ANSWER**

```
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()
'Thanks to code by Tim Williams and Ron de Bruin

'    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
'    On Error Resume Next
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim ci As Long
'    Set rng = Nothing
    Dim str As String
    str = Empty
    
    For Each cell In Sheet1.Range("C4:Z100").Cells
        ci = cell.Interior.ColorIndex
        If (ci = -4142 Or ci = 2 Or ci = 15 Or ci = 16) And Not IsNumeric(cell.value) Then
        '****************************************************************************
'            If rng Is Nothing Then
'                Set rng = cell
'            Else
'                Set rng = Application.Union(rng, cell)
'            End If
            str = str & CStr(cell.value) & " "
        '****************************************************************************
        End If
    Next cell
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
'    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "teacher1@school.org, teacher2@school.org"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the list of students with missing work"
        
        '****************************************************************************
        Dim wdDoc As Object
        Dim olinsp As Object
        
        Set wdDoc = CreateObject("Word.Document")
        Set olinsp = .GetInspector
        Set wdDoc = olinsp.WordEditor
        
        If Not IsEmpty(str) Then
            wdDoc.Range.InsertBefore str
            .Display
            .Send
        Else
            MsgBox prompt:="No cells meet the criteria"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        '****************************************************************************
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set olinsp = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

So, I'm not sure this gives you the intended result, however after testing with a test worksheet I successfully displayed the email with all the relevant cell values separated by a space (you can choose whatever you want to separate the values, you just need to replace the " " on the line containing `str = str & CStr(cell.value) & " "` .

I changed where the .Send method is on the code so that no email is sent if there are no relevant cells.

I fail to understand how are you going to know which student hasn't yet submitted the assignment as the relevant cells contain only the initial of the teacher? Or am I getting this wrong?

If you need to include the student's name also for each cell value then the code can be easily modified to do that, however I'm not sure that I fully understand what is the desired output is here.

Anyways let me know how it goes.

**ADDITION**

You can output a single line like this: studentA_J studentB_F studentC_W , J F and W being the initials of the teachers. In order to achieve that you need only the the line containing `str = str & CStr(cell.value) & " "` and change it to `str = str & Sheet1.Cells(cell.row,j) & "_" & CStr(cell.value) & " "` , where j needs to be the index of the column where the student's name is.

If I remember correctly you can even write it using the letter of the column, for example if the students names are in column A then you can also replace the above line of code also by `str = str & Sheet1.Cells(cell.row,"A") & "_" & CStr(cell.value) & " "`

**UPGRADED CODE**

```
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()
'Thanks to code by Tim Williams and Ron de Bruin

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range, studentCell As Range
    Dim ci As Long
    Dim str As String
    str = Empty
    
    With Application
        .calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .DisplayStatusBar = False
        .enableEvents = False
        .screenUpdating = False
        .Interactive = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .AskToUpdateLinks = False
    End With
    
    For Each cell In Sheet1.Range("C4:Z100").Cells
        ci = cell.Interior.ColorIndex
        If (ci = -4142 Or ci = 2 Or ci = 15 Or ci = 16) And Not IsNumeric(cell.value) Then
        '****************************************************************************
            Set studentCell = Sheet1.Cells(cell.Row, "A")
            
            With cell
                If Not .CommentThreaded Is Nothing Then
                    str = str & studentCell.value & "_" & CStr(.value) & "_" & .CommentThreaded.Text & vbCrLf
                Else
                    str = str & studentCell.value & "_" & CStr(.value) & vbCrLf
                End If
            End With
        '****************************************************************************
        End If
    Next cell
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    With OutMail
        .To = "teacher1@school.org, teacher2@school.org"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the list of students with missing work"
        
        '****************************************************************************
        Dim wdDoc As Object
        Dim olinsp As Object
        
        Set wdDoc = CreateObject("Word.Document")
        Set olinsp = .GetInspector
        Set wdDoc = olinsp.WordEditor
        
        If Not IsEmpty(str) Then
            wdDoc.Range.InsertBefore str
        Else
            MsgBox prompt:="No cells meet the criteria"
            GoTo SafeExit
        End If
        '****************************************************************************
        .Display
        .Send
    End With
    
SafeExit:
    With Application
        .calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .DisplayStatusBar = False
        .enableEvents = False
        .screenUpdating = False
        .Interactive = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .AskToUpdateLinks = False
    End With
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set olinsp = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

If you use this upgraded code then it will run much faster.

Comment: Thanks David. Trying your code, I'm getting a run-time error 429 - ActiveX component can't create object. In Tools >> References, I have these checked: VB for Applications, MS Excel 16 OL, OLE Automation, MS Office 16 OL, MS Outlook 16 OL, MS ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 L, and now MS Word 16 OL.

Comment: Hi @middleschoolteacher, I have updated the code, I made a mistake before. Check it out now. It'll work even if you don't check the references as it uses late binding.

Comment: Thank you so much David for working on this more. When I run the updated code, I'm getting a run-time error 1004. I won't have a chance to look at it again until later this afternoon. Thanks though.

Comment: Welcome, when you get the chance to check the error could you point out at which line you get it? Thanks

Comment: It errored at Set wdDoc = CreateObject("Word.Document"), so I changed this line to Set wdDoc = CreateObject("Word.Application"). Then the debugger was able to go past this line. Now, the same error is happening at this line: wdDoc.Range(1, 1).Paste

Comment: It won't work like that, you need the object Word.Document, the weird thing is that when I test the code here the object is created without any problems... I do get the 1004 error on the copy operation. I'll post an update so you can try again

Comment: So, with Word.Document, at the "If Not rng Is Nothing Then" line near the bottom, I'm now getting run-time error -2147467259 (800004005).

Comment: Are you sure you're using the code in the updated answer? Because I have commented out that line of code and I'm not even using the rng Range object, it's not even created at runtime. Replace your entire code with the one I wrote on the updated answer and then try it.

Comment: Hi David. Yes, it does work now. I'm not sure why it errored yesterday. The error was probably me. Thank you so much. Your code creates a string of the letters that are in the various columns, and puts the letters in a line in the Outlook email body. My next challenge will be to also select and include the student's name in column A if there is one of the letter values selected in the same row, and then build the email's body in a way that puts each student along with their letter(s) on a separate line. I'll try to research it some. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @middleschoolteacher hello that should be relatively easy to achieve, do you have a mockup screenshot showing the structure of your data? You can output 2 lines on the email or you can output a single line like this: studentA_J studentB_F studentC_W . J F and W being the initals of the teachers. In order to achieve that you need only the the line containing 'str = str & CStr(cell.value) & " " ' and change it to 'str = str & Sheet1.Cells(cell.row,j) & "_" & CStr(cell.value) & " " ' , where j needs to be the index of the column where the student's name is. CHECK OUT the ADDITION part.

Comment: Wow. Thank you once again David. One more issue-somewhat related to this original topic. In all of the cells with letters for the teachers' initial, the teachers right-click and add a comment, summarizing the missing work. We'd also like to include the text of the comment of each cell that's in the range. I tried to modify your string code but am now getting a run-time error 91 - object var or with block var not set. An additional thanks if you could help troubleshoot this: str = str & Sheet1.Cells(cell.Row, "A") & "_" & CStr(cell.Value) & "_" & cell.CommentThreaded.Text & " " & vbCrLf

Comment: Yay, the following code now works. I was mixing cell.comment and cell.threadedcomment, and apparently Excel doesn't like this:  If Not cell.CommentThreaded Is Nothing Then
            str = str & Sheet1.Cells(cell.Row, "A") & "_" & CStr(cell.Value) & "_" & cell.CommentThreaded.Text & vbCrLf
            Else
            str = str & Sheet1.Cells(cell.Row, "A") & "_" & CStr(cell.Value) & vbCrLf
            End If

Comment: Good one!! You found the answer before I could find out what was going on!

Comment: @middleschoolteacher , if you use the UPGRADED CODE it will run much faster.

Comment: Thanks David. I'm going to use this across 2 sheets for 2 different grades, and will attach it to the click of a cell (button) on each sheet to make it easy for any of the teachers to run. Again, much appreciated.